# Sending an SMS for specific email notifications and order statuses

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

With WooCommerce I use a special theme that handle bookings for motorbikes and scooters rental service. I want to get the order related data. I am trying to send an SMS when an email notification is sent to customer for **`completed`**, **`on hold`**, **`pending`** and **`processing**` order status.

I have use the code below for instance that output the data I need in SMS:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$status = $order->get_status(); // order status

if( 'completed' == $status || 'processing' == $status || 'pending' == $status || 'on-hold' == $status ){

    $user_phone = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_phone', true); 

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {

        $product_id = $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_product_id', true); // product ID
        $product_name = get_post($product_id)->post_title; // Product description

        // Related Booking data to insert in SMS
        $book_check_in  = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_check_in', true );
        $book_check_out = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_check_out', true );
        $book_pick_up   = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_pick_up', true );
        $book_drop_off  = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_drop_off', true );

    }
    // Send SMS in SMS API
    file_get_contents("http://144.76.39.175/api.php?username=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&route=1&message%5B%5D=The+message&sender=NBWREN&mobile%5B%5D=xxxxxxxxxxx");

}
```

This is not working. Where should I hook this code? I tried different templates and all I got were some 500 errors or simply nothing happened.

Please give me some help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message in the 500 exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_email_order_details`** hook, using included **`$order`** and **`$email`** objects.

You will be able to rearrange the message as you like, as this is just an example.

I have commented this code to make you understand how it works:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_details', 'send_sms_on_email_notifications', 10, 4);
function send_sms_on_email_notifications($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){

    $order_id       = $order->id; // get the order ID for Order object 
    $email_id       = $email->id; // get the email ID for Email object 
    $order_status   = $order->get_status(); // Get order Status

    // Array of Email IDs to avoid Admin email notifications (SMS sent twice on some notifications)
    $emails_ids_exceptions  = array('new_order', 'failed_order', 'customer_invoice', 'customer_note');

    // Your targeted order status
    $order_statuses = array('completed', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'pending');

    $send_the_sms = false;

    // Just for your targeted order statuses
    if( in_array( $order_status, $order_statuses ) ):

        // iterating in the order items
        foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item):

            $prod_id   = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', true ); // product ID
            $prod_name = get_post($prod_id)->post_title; // Product Name

            $mobile    = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_phone', true); // mobile phone

            // Related Booking data to insert in SMS
            $check_in  = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_check_in', true );
            $check_out = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_check_out', true );
            $pick_up   = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_pick_up', true );
            $drop_off  = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id, '_st_drop_off', true );

            // stoping the loop (just for one item)
            break;

        endforeach;

        // Limiting to customer email notifications
        if( !in_array( $email_id, $emails_ids_exceptions ) )
        {
            // inserting the order data (variables) in the message
            $text = "Your order $order_id with $status status, for $prod_name. Your booking details: Check in time: $check_in, Check out Time: $check_out, Pick up $pick_up and drop of Time is $drop_off";

            $send_the_sms = true;
        }

        // TRIGGERING THE SMS
        if($send_the_sms)
        {
            // Replacing spaces by '+' in the message
            $message = str_replace(' ', '+', $text);

            // Inserting the message and the user number phone in the URL
            $url = "http://144.76.39.175/api.php?username=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&route=1&message%5B%5D=$message&sender=NBWREN&mobile%5B%5D=$mobile";

            // Triggering the SMS
            file_get_contents($url);
        }

    endif;

}
```

This code will work for the first item of the order, assuming that people rent one bike or one scooter at the time.
The code is mainly tested, but I can't guaranty the triggered SMS as I can't test it on your SMS API. I hope this will work… Let me know.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply let me check

Comment: exactly was expecting for same thing thanks it really helped me alot ..:)

Comment: @Shaik I was not so sure of the SMS generated URL… Very happy that is working. I have learned also a lot around $email object in that woocommerce email templates…