# Can not get the product details from order_id on the new order hook function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

With WooCommerce, I have the following hook in my **`function.php`** after the new order is submitted:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_job_openings');
function create_job_openings($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $item) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        var_dump($product_name);
    }
}
```

The above code is not giving me any output i'e it is not entering inside the **`foreach`** loop that's why **`var_dump()`** not giving me any output, but if I mention the **`order_id`** specifically like **`create_job_openings($order_id=517)`** it works, even I tried echo **`$order_id`** before **`foreach`** loop, it is giving me the **`order_id`**, then why it is not entering the **`foreach`** loop?

note: when I try **`var_dump($items);`** before **`foreach`** loop its giving me

```
array(0) {
}
```

Why it is not able to get the product details even if there are products in it after new order is made?

Comment: did you check $order_id is really coming ??

Comment: do one thing call global woocommerce in function

Comment: @sam check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details

Comment: @LoicTheAztec wc_get_order gives me the correct output, great! but can it be used like $items = $order->get_items()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Update 2 — The working solution** *(using an email notification hook)*

The problem is when using email notification hook can fire an action **2 times**, for example when a new order is made (notification for the Shop manager and notification for the customer).

*You want to use this "New Order" event for Orders that are in "processing" status.*

> **To avoid your action to be fired 2 times** using New order notification WooCommerce event, we use **`'customer_processing_order'`** instead of **`'new_order'`** email ID *(notification event)*.

Here we don't need to get the **`$order`** object, as we got it as an argument in this hooked function.

So here is your final functional code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    if( 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id ){ // for processing order status customer notification…
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values) {
            $product_name = $item_values['name'];
            echo $product_name;
            break; // (optional) stop loop to first item
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the validated and working answer to this question**

Related Working Answers:

- [Sending an SMS for specific email notifications and order statuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100316/sending-an-sms-for-specific-email-notifications-and-order-statuses/41101162#41101162)
- [Avoid repetitive emails notification on some auto completed orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074461/avoid-repetitive-emails-notification-on-some-auto-completed-orders/41074630#41074630)
- [Change the user role on purchase for specific products when order status is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510007/change-the-user-role-on-purchase-for-specific-products-when-order-status-is-comp/41517132#41517132)

---

> **Update 1** *(hook alternative)*

Trying using **`woocommerce_thankyou`** hook, that is fired on review order after order has been processed:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'create_job_openings', 10, 1 );
function create_job_openings( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values) {
        $product_name = $item_values['name'];
        var_dump($product_name);
        break; // (optional) stop loop to first item
    }
}
```

*(Not working for the OP)*

---

You should try this instead [**`wc_get_order()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order.html) function this way and your code will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_job_openings', 10, 1);
function create_job_openings($order_id) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item_values) {
        $product_name = $item_values['name'];
        var_dump($product_name);
        break; // (optional) stops on first item
    }
}
```

You can have a look to
[How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/39409201#39409201) where a lot of things are explained…

*(Not working for the OP)*

Answer (score 1):

you can use `save_post` action when post is added in wordpress. for more visit: [Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

```
function wc_order_add_action($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // If this isn't a 'shop_order' post, don't update it.
    if ("shop_order" != $post_type) return;

    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

    foreach($order -> get_items() as $key => $item)
    {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        var_dump($product_name);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'wc_order_add_action');
```

Comment: why i need to save_post? i just want action hook to perform something once the new order is placed

Comment: order is added as post in wordpress. @sam

Comment: @sam woocommerce plugin store order as post type "shop_order" in database. :)

Comment: @sam I have updated my answer please check now. hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't want to save each order as post!

Comment: Hey @sam bydefault woocommerce store order as post_type. I just add action that execute after post is added.

Answer (score 1):

To get the items and product details from the new order, you simply need to request two parameters for `woocommerce_new_order`.  The second passed parameter will be the new order object.  Example:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'so41605256_new_order', 10, 2 );
function so41605256_new_order( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Directly access items from $order variable, do not use wc_get_order...
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This works for both programmatically created and user created orders, regardless of WC email configuration.

Reference: `create` and `update` methods in `WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT` core class.  Kudos to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813346/144813) which helped me discover this.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. I fixed it by changing the hook to `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`. It works perfectly for both instant payment and cash on delivery since it runs as soon as an order is placed. Note that, this will run before payment completion. So, it doesn't have any relation with payment.

User clicks on proceed to checkout button and then this hook fires.